# TCPDF is drawing a line over text and a strikethrough on the text

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have used TCPDF with great success but have come across something I can't seem to fix.

This image shows what's happening. There are lines being drawn over the text and a strikethrough is being applied to the text, I don't want either of these.

[image]

Here is the code. I've tried this with cell() and text() and get the same results. Except for the unwanted lines this is working fine. Any ideas of what's going on here?

TCPDF Version is 6.2.5

```
    $pdf = new TCPDF('L', 'in', array($cardHeight,$cardWidth),TRUE,"UTF-8"); 

    $pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
    $pdf->SetMargins(0, 0, 0);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(FALSE, 0);  
    $pdf->AddPage();

    $cardData = json_decode($this->getData());

    $frontData = $cardData->front->fields;

    foreach ($frontData as $key => $value) {

        $alignment = strtoupper($value->align[0]);
        $w = $value->w/$dpiCorrection;
        $h = $value->h/$dpiCorrection;

        $cmyk = $this->rgb2cmyk( $this->hex2RGB($value->color) );
        $text = trim($value->text);
        $pdf->SetFont($value->font, $value->weight, $value->size);
        $pdf->SetTextColor((int)$cmyk['c'], (int)$cmyk['m'], (int)$cmyk['y'], (int)$cmyk['k']);

        // $pdf->SetXY($value->x/$dpiCorrection, $value->y/$dpiCorrection);
         // $pdf->Cell(
         //     $w,         // width
         //     $h,         // height
         //     $text,      // text
         //     0,          // border
         //     0,          // ln - current postion after call
         //     $alignment, // L, C, R, or justify alignment
         //     0,          // fill 1 = painted, 0 = transparent
         //     '',         // link
         //     0,          // font stretch mode
         //     1,          // 1 = ignore automatic minimum height value
         //     '',         // cell vertical alignment, relative to specified Y value
         //     ''          // text vertical alignment
         //     );
         // $pdf->Cell(0,0,"Testing".$key);

        $pdf->Text($value->x/$dpiCorrection, $value->y/$dpiCorrection, "testing ".$key);
    }

    $filename = storage_path() . '/test.pdf';
    $pdf->output('test', 'D'); // 'D' force download, 'I' show inline

    $headers = array(
      'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
    );
```

This is the output with border set to 1.

[image]

Comment: Just wanted to note that the `strikethrough` might as well be the bottom border and the text is overflowing it,

Comment: What would be the result of trying `$pdf->Text($value->x/$dpiCorrection, $value->y/$dpiCorrection, "");`? Also, please update your question with the exact version of TCPDF because even minor revisions can have severely different quirks.

Comment: Does your output look different if you pass `1` to the border-parameter?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, your suggestion results in a blank document. I'm using TCPDF version 6.2.5.

Comment: @maja, I posted a screen shot with border =1.

Comment: Does this also happen with a different font and TCPDF version? Maybe your pdf viewer doesn't display it correctly? I can't find any problems in your code...

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out. Simple thing, kind of.

In this bit of code the value for `$value->weight` was 'bold'.

```
$pdf->SetFont($value->font, $value->weight, $value->size);
```

That doesn't work. Seems TCPDF is quite specific about this. So the final answer, for me anyway, was to do this:

```
$fweight = strtoupper($value->weight[0]);
$pdf->SetFont("$value->font", "$fweight", $value->size);
```

Thanks to those that helped with this.